# Does putting all of your code between mutex_lock and mutex_unlock render multithreaded(ness) meaningless

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Say I'm writing a multi threaded server which takes in different database queries from a client, looks up the database and gives back results.

If I put ALL of my server code to receive the client query, database lookup and response to client within mutex_lock and mutex_unlock, doesn't it mean that a new thread has to wait for the entire code to be executed? So isn't this similar to just running a for-loop for all the client requests for a single-threaded server?

I feel the only difference would be that a for loop executes from 1 to 100, say in sequence, but for a loop like below, the order of threads cannot be predicted

```
pthread_t th[100];
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
 pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, fun, NULL);
}
```

Am I right in saying so?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean with only a single lock where each thread does all its work under the protection of the very same lock.

Comment: Yes I meant a block where one single mutex-lock mutex-unlock spans the entire block. Thanks @DavidSchwartz  for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book C++ Concurrency in Action, Anthony Williams says there are two main reasons to use concurrency:

1. performance
2. separation of concerns

optional reason

3. because I want to

You are right, creating 100 threads and then serializing them all on one mutex makes multithreaded-ness meaningless, it actually hurts #1 and does nothing for #2.  It will burden the operating system with 100 threads, only one of which can run at a time because the rest will be blocked/serialized waiting on the mutex, it will incur unnecessary context switch overhead, and the overhead of the mutex itself.

A server servicing database requests should be multi-threaded, for both #1 and #2.

New threads could be created when a new requests arrive. The alternative is to [use a thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).  One thread accepts requests, and creates a new thread (or enqueues to the thread pool) to handle the request then goes back to accept another request.  See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261482/multithreaded-server-issue).  Whether you need to serialize on a mutex or not to access the database depends on the database, most allow concurrent connections, see [this answer for MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883178/multithreading-in-mysql)